# display specific rows from a table using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to display a table with 100 rows and i want to show the first 20 rows and hide the others at first..and after that the next 20 rows until we reached 100 rows...I am new using jQuery so i don't know how to do it i have tried something like this but its definitely wrong

> PHP

```
<?php 
 $sql = "SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY jloc_title ASC) AS  Rownum,jloc_id, jloc_title 
FROM Locations";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($connection,$sql);
if($stmt == false)
{
 echo"Error (sqlsrv_query):".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true);
 exit;
}
while($row1=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
    {
    $id = $row1[0];
    $title = $row1[1];
    $Rownumber = $row1[2];              
    echo"<tr id='Row' value='".$Rownumber."'    >";
    echo"<td class='text-center'> " .$Rownumber.  "</td>";
    echo"<td class='text-center'> " .$id. "</td>";
    echo"<td class='text-center'> " .$title. "</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
    }
?>
```

> jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var number = document.getElementById("table1").rows.length ;
var counter= 0 ;
for (i=0; i<=number; i+=20) {   
    if (counter == 0) { 
        if (number > 20) {  
            var $rows = $("#table1 tr");
            $rows.eq(21).hide();
            ...
            $rows.eq(100).hide();
        }
        counter++;
    }
    else if (counter == 1) {
        while (counter == 1 ) {
            if (number > 40 ) {
                var $rows = $("#table1 tr");
                $rows.eq(0).hide();
                ...
                $rows.eq(21).hide();
                $rows.eq(60).hide();
                ...
                $rows.eq(100).hide();                                   
            }
            counter++;
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }

    setInterval(function(){location.reload();}, 1000*10);
}
});
```

Comment: You can use this jquery library - http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_basic-usage

Comment: you either want to load all your data and just hide the rows you don't want to display first with jQuery -> this has nothing to do with php - or you create a service endpoint that will give you a specific amount / set of rows that you can then `$.get()` with jQuery -> this you would want to do if loading data takes a considerable amount of time

Comment: is there any way to hide the rows and not write every single row individually?